# Swift 3.+ Conforming Equatable - Internal and static OR global approach?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, swift-protocols

I'm working with the "Equatable" protocol in some projects, but I'm wondering... What's the actual difference between satisfying the protocol requirements via a *global solution* and via a *static solution* (available from swift 3)?

Example:

```
class ExampleClass {
    let value: Int = 0
}

// #1: Global Approach
extension ExampleClass: Equatable { }

func == (lhs: ExampleClass, rhs: ExampleClass) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

// #2: Internal static approach (Swift 3+)
extension ExampleClass: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: ExampleClass, rhs: ExampleClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}
```

The result seems the same, but the second approach seems just cleaner to me. But there's actually a real difference in practice? 
At the end we're doing in both cases an overloading.

My possible answer to this is simply that before swift 3 the: `public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` was declared in another way, but I'm just assuming it!

Comment: I don't think there's any difference functionally, but `Equatable` states that you need to provide the `static` method. Personally, using the `static` method in the class/struct (or in an extension) is better because it is clear that it is part of the class/struct. The use of the global is less obvious because it just sort of hangs outside of the class/struct (or extension).

Comment: The global debate continues in OOP and probably will forever. On the machine level, a global object is really not much different from a Swift `static` object--their "exposure" and "availability" is practically the same. This is why there is no real difference in performance and why the debate to use globals goes on. `static` however leans more on the side of encapsulation, which is a tenet of OOP, and I think that's the ultimate reason why `static` will win this round. There isn't much stopping you from making an app entirely of global properties and methods, except your job security.

Comment: Ok, I see! thank you very much for the answers.